# Python generate all possible configurations of numbers on a "board"

Tags: python, list

I am trying to take an input number of "filled squares" and generate all possible configurations of those squares on an n by n board (list of lists). Empty squares are denoted 0, filled squares 1. For example, on a 2x2 grid with three filled squares, the possible configurations are:

```
[[1 1]
 [1 0]]

[[1 1]
 [0 1]]

[[1 0]
 [1 1]]

[[0 1]
 [1 1]]
```

Each time the function generates one of these configurations it copies it and appends it to a list (configList). Here is my idea (below), but when I started writing the code for it it seemed monstrously more complex than it had to be. Is there a more efficient way to do this for an n by n board with x number of tents (filled squares represent tents), and how would I implement this in python?

```
def findConfigs(config):
    configList = []
    place tents sequentially on the board

    loop:
    find last tent's location
        for each following position on the board:
            move last tent to this position
            newConfig = deepcopy(config)
            configList.append(newConfig)
        # last tent has reached the end of the board, so-
        find the previous tent
        if next position is not occupied by the following tent:
            move it forward
            move following tents directly after
        else: # the previous tent cannot move any further
            find next previous tent
            if next position is not occupied by the following tent...
        go back to loop

    return configList
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `combinations` to generate the positions of the `0`s

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> list(combinations(range(4), 1))
[(0,), (1,), (2,), (3,)]
```

Just map the numbers 0,1,2,3 onto your 2x2 grid.

A larger example is probably more convincing

```
>>> list(combinations(range(9), 2))
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 8), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7), (3, 8), (4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8), (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (6, 7), (6, 8), (7, 8)]
```

Here's an example mapping to a 2D list

```
>>> from itertools import product, combinations
>>> n = 3 # 3x3
>>> m = 2 # 2 tents
>>> for i in combinations(range(n*n), m):
...    print [[0 if x*n+y in i else 1 for x in range(n)] for y in range(n)]
... 
[[0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
[[0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]]
[[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
[[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
[[0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1]]
[[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
[[0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
[[0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0]]
[[1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]]
[[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
[[1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
[[1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1]]
[[1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
[[1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
[[1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0]]
[[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]]
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]]
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1]]
[[1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]]
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1]]
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0]]
[[1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
[[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1]]
[[1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
[[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
[[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0]]
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1]]
[[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0]]
[[1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1]]
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0]]
[[1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
[[1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0]]
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: This is much better than what I was thinking, which was to make `[1,1,1,0]` and then permute it, because that way you have to handle the fact that you get multiple `(1,1,1,0)`s because the permutation is by position.

Answer (score 0):

So I take it you are not taking into account rotations or reflections. You could take another approach to the problem... how many empty spaces do I have? Lets say we have `n`. Well, can't we achieve all possible board configurations by finding all possible places we can 'insert' these `n` empty squares into an entirely filled board? For this we can use the `itertools` import, and arrange all possible configurations, specifically, as gnibbler has pointed out, `combinations`.