# Generate all possible board positions of tic tac toe

Tags: python, algorithm

This is somewhat similar to this question : [Python generate all possible configurations of numbers on a "board"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20509723/python-generate-all-possible-configurations-of-numbers-on-a-board) but I'm trying to implement in Python and I want to include generated boards that are just partially complete.

In tic tac toe there are 3^9 (19683) board positions.

Here is my code to generate each board where each element of the board array is a single board :

```
boards = []
temp_boards = []

for i in range(0 , 19683) : 
    c = i
    temp_boards = []
    for ii in range(0 , 9) : 
        temp_boards.append(c % 3)
        c = c // 3
    boards.append(temp_boards)
```

- 0 corresponds to O
- 1 corresponds to X
- 2 corresponds to 'position not yet filled'

Could I have missed any positions ?

Comment: Is a board with 9 X's acceptable?

Comment: @ScottHunter No, just where three X's or O's are aligned and a mix of X or O or nothing in remaining positions.

Comment: Then this code generates a *LOT* of unacceptable boards.

Comment: So a board filled w/ 'positions not yet filled' is not acceptable?

Comment: @ScottHunter an empty board is acceptable, in this case would be 9 None values.

Comment: Where are the "three X's or O's are aligned" in an empty board?

Comment: @ScottHunter "No, just where three X's or O's are aligned and a mix of X or O or nothing in remaining positions." should read "No, just where three X's or O's are aligned or a mix of X or O or nothing in remaining positions."

Comment: There's also the issue of symmetry. For example, consider a board with 1 X and 8 empty. Are there 9 positions for the X, or only 3 (center, corner, side)?

Comment: A board of 9 X's satisfies your new definition (the one where you replaced "and" with "or").

Comment: @user3386109 "There's also the issue of symmetry. For example, consider a board with 1 X and 8 empty. Are there 9 positions for the X, or only 3 (center, corner, side)? –" there are 0 moves available until O will move after which which leaves 7 possible positions for X. So there are 7 possible positions for X.

Comment: Lol, so basically you're saying that O goes first. In that case, are there 9 choices for O, or only 3? Please [edit] the question to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you consider that players take turns and the game stops when someone wins, there will be fewer possible boards than the maximum combinations of X, O and blank cells would suggest.  You also cannot count boards filled with all Xs or all Os or any combinations that would have a difference greater than 1 between the number of Xs and Os.

You can obtain that number by recursively simulating moves starting with X and starting with O:

```
axes = [(0,1,2),(3,4,5),(6,7,8),(0,3,6),(1,4,7),(2,5,8),(0,4,8),(2,4,6)]

def isWin(board):
    return any("".join(board[p] for p in axis) in ["XXX","OOO"] for axis in axes)

def validBoards(board="."*9,player=None):
    if player == None:
        yield board  # count the empty board
        for b in validBoards(board,player="X"): yield b # X goes 1st
        for b in validBoards(board,player="O"): yield b # O goes 1st
        return
    opponent = "XO"[player=="X"]
    for pos,cell in enumerate(board):
        if cell != ".": continue
        played = board[:pos]+player+board[pos+1:] # simulate move
        yield played                              # return the new state
        if isWin(played): continue                # stop game upon winning
        for nextBoard in validBoards(played,opponent):
            yield nextBoard # return boards for subsequent moves
```

output:

```
distinctBoards = set(validBoards())  # only look at distinct board states

allStates = len(distinctBoards)
print(allStates)  # 8533 counting all intermediate states

winningStates = sum(isWin(b) for b in  distinctBoards)
print(winningStates) # 1884  (so 942 for a specific starting player)

filledStates  = sum(("." not in b) for b in distinctBoards)        
print(filledStates) #  156 states where all cells are filled 

finalStates  = sum(isWin(b) or ("." not in b) for b in distinctBoards)        
print(finalStates) #  1916 end of game states (win or draw) 

earlyWins = sum(isWin(b) and ("." in b) for b in distinctBoards)
print(earlyWins) # 1760 wins before filling the board

draws  = finalStates - winningStates        
print(draws) #  32 ways to end up in a draw 

lastWins = filledStates-draws
print(lastWins) # 124 wins on the 9th move (i.e filling the board)

fastWins = sum( isWin(b) and b.count(".") == 4 for b in distinctBoards)
print(fastWins) # 240 fastest wins by 1st player (in 3 moves)

fastCounters = sum( isWin(b) and b.count(".") == 3 for b in distinctBoards)
print(fastCounters) # 296 fastest wins by 2nd player (in 3 moves)
```

If you need a faster implementation, here is an optimized version of the function that only returns distinct states and leverages this to skip whole branches of the move sequence tree:

```
def validBoards(board="."*9,player=None,states=None):
    if player == None:
        result  = {board}  # count the empty board
        result |= validBoards(board,player="X",states=set()) # X goes 1st
        result |= validBoards(board,player="O",states=set()) # O goes 1st
        return result
    opponent = "XO"[player=="X"]
    for pos,cell in enumerate(board):
        if cell != ".": continue
        played = board[:pos]+player+board[pos+1:] # simulate move
        if played in states : continue            # skip duplicate states
        states.add(played)                        # return the new state
        if isWin(played): continue                # stop game upon winning 
        validBoards(played,opponent,states)       # add subsequent moves 
    return states
```

Comment: How much duplication is there in the value returned by `validBoards`?

Comment: `validBoards()` returns board states for all sequences of moves (including states after 1 move, 2 moves, etc.) so there are quite a few duplicate states in there (1,091,358 out of 1,099,891).

Comment: So 99% are duplicates?!?

Comment: 99% of move sequences yes but only 56% of possible combinations.